# Invalid object name error when adding a defaulted constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Scenario: I have to create a table that has historical data. I added a Record_ID column with the ROW_NUM, it has 100 records.

Task: I want to automatically continue the RECORD_ID to any appended new records. I found the piece of code below elsewhere but when I run it, I get the error below. Not sure how I can add a constraint so that my  Row_Number (record_id) column automatically adds the next sequential number.

[image]

`ALTER TABLE [SCHEMA].[TEST1] ADD CONSTRAINT [df_seq_nj]  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [df_seq_nj]) FOR [RECORD_ID]`

Comment: Thats because you are missing a sequence called `dj_seq_nj`

Comment: I am relatively new to SQL, what exactly does missing a sequence mean? I have never really added a column that does this so, I am lost.

Comment: If you google "SQL Server sequence", and google "SQL Server NEXT VALUE FOR" and then read through the documentation and then see if you have any questions. I can't explain it better than the docs can :)

Comment: I did find it, thank you so much!